# jQuery load event fire when html code is appended

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, load

I am using jQuery's ajax function `$.get()` to download data from a page. I then cast that data to a jQuery object with `$(data)`, allowing it to construct a DOM tree. I then append this data using `append()`

Is there a way for jQuery to fire an event similar to `load` which would tell me when the data's iframes/images/videos are done loading? Either before or after the `append()`?

According to the jQuery documentation, the `load` event only fires on specific objects:

> This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

I could loop through all of the data and attach a `load` listener to each of these objects, then count how many there are and have the `load` handler count how many have loaded (or have already been cached) until the number reaches the total. However I am looking for an alternative to this solution.

I have tried to attach the `load` event to the `window` object through `load()` and `on()` but these only fire once when the active page is initially loaded.

Here is my code:

```
$.get(url_string, function(data) {
    // Create DOM elements out of the downloaded html text 'data'
    // and take a subset of the DOM elements, where the id is #content
    var myContents = $(data).find("#content");

    // Insert DOM elements into the active page
    $("#destination").append(myContents);

    // Check when all images/iframes/video elements have loaded
    // Does not work
    $("#destination").load(function() {
        alert("new stuff loaded");
    });

    // Does not work either
    myContents.load(function() {
        alert("new stuff loaded");
    });
});
```

This question is linked to

- [jquery event once all images are loaded (including cached images)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625918/jquery-event-once-all-images-are-loaded-including-cached-images)
- [jQuery event for images loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910727/jquery-event-for-images-loaded)
- [jquery: event for when ajax loaded content is all loaded (including images)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488874/jquery-event-for-when-ajax-loaded-content-is-all-loaded-including-images)

but the solution offered in these are all the one I mentioned above, where I would have to count how many of the objects there are, then check when the total is reached.

Comment: A jsFiddle demo would be helpful to exactly show this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the latest version of jQuery (1.8.2) doesn't have support for firing DOM ready events when HTML is appended.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to assign load events after content is loaded. Define them before appending the content.

Try this one,

```
$.get(url_string, function(data) {
    // Create DOM elements out of the downloaded html text 'data'
    // and take a subset of the DOM elements, where the id is #content
    var myContents = $(data).find("#content");

    // Check when all images/iframes/video elements have loaded
    $("#destination").load(function() {
        alert("new stuff loaded");
    });

    myContents.load(function() {
        alert("new stuff loaded");
    });

    // Insert DOM elements into the active page
    $("#destination").append(myContents);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ocanal! I tried this out but it did not work. This is understandable since `load()` isn't designed to be attached to tags other than those mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Your answer might be confusing to the reader since you've kept all the original comments that say, `does not work`, `does not work either`, etc.