# Run js code on page load when using *.js.erb-view in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

On a "normal" html.erb view I run js code on page load by including something like this in application.js

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
   $("#yield_wrap").css({"opacity":"1"});
});
```

How can I accomplish something similar when the page/content is loaded by a javascript-view (e.g. show.js.erb)?

Comment: not clear about your requirement. on loading a page content do you want to click a link and load something?

Comment: See my comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/18849012/1417223

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand your question completely, the `show.js.erb` will just contain the javascript that is executed in the browser. You do not have to wait for an event.

Comment: And if I want to run something on what the `show.js.erb` has rendered? I need to truncate some text (client-side), but need the page (including web-fonts) to load completely first.

Comment: I would assume that the webfonts would be loaded already, or are you adding new webfonts through ajax? You need the rendered size to be able  to correctly get the width of the text? If that is the case, I wuld suggest changing the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488874/jquery-event-for-when-ajax-loaded-content-is-all-loaded-including-images